# Out Of Memory exception when using web3j in Android

Tags: web3j, android, java

I'm trying to integrate web3j in an android application. But the library gives an Out Of Memory exception when loading the wallet file:

```
Credentials credentials = WalletUtils.loadCredentials("password", walletFile)
```

This is the exception:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 268435468 byte allocation with 8050708 free bytes and 244MB until OOM
```

This seems to be the culprit:

```
//com.lambdaworks.crypto.SCrypt#scryptJ
byte[] V  = new byte[128 * r * N]; // r: 8, N: 262144, V = byte[268435456]
```

I know that the credentials can be loaded because another project, [Ether Wallet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vikulin.etherwallet), uses web3j and is able to load the same wallet file. Can someone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: I got exactly the same error while was trying to create a wallet. In my case, the problem was `useFullScrypt` which was set to `true` setting it to `false` solved the problem. Didn't have time yet to investigate the problem but as I checked the KPF params are different in those cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a quick hack. Create a `jniLibs` folder in `/src/main` and add all the android folders from [this](https://github.com/haochenx/scrypt/tree/master/src/android/resources/lib) scrypt fork into the `jniLibs` folder. Build. Run

I'll update with a more correct solution if/when I find one.

Note: Requires gradle 0.7.2+ for the jniLibs to be added to the build automatically

Answer (score 0):

This is still happening.

decrypt method (`org.web3j.crypto`)
calls
generatedDerivedScryptKey (`org.web3j.crypto`)
calls
generate in SCrypt (`org.spongycastle.crypto.generators`)..

it all comes down to the size of the Array, initialized by parameter N:

```
WalletFile.KdfParams kdfParams = crypto.getKdfparams();
if (kdfParams instanceof WalletFile.ScryptKdfParams) {
    WalletFile.ScryptKdfParams scryptKdfParams =
                (WalletFile.ScryptKdfParams) crypto.getKdfparams();
    int dklen = scryptKdfParams.getDklen();
    int n = scryptKdfParams.getN();
    int p = scryptKdfParams.getP();
    int r = scryptKdfParams.getR();
    byte[] salt = Numeric.hexStringToByteArray(scryptKdfParams.getSalt());
    derivedKey = generateDerivedScryptKey(
                password.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")), salt, n, r, p, dklen);
```

N  IS THE CORE PROBLEM